# compare mongodb database schema, apply difference

Tags: mongodb, schema

I know mongodb doesn't have schema as such but i am not sure what to call it. Database structure?

My question is... Is there a tool or way to compare two or more databases in mongodb to get the difference and apply the changes.
Not the data.
Just the structure such as indexes.

Example: Lets say i have 5 databases for different clients, and i decide i want to create a new index in one of the collections. I want to then apply that change to all my other databases with ease.

Comment: i have been using for mariadb this: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/  which is great. just wish they had one for mongodb

Comment: mmmm it resembles much more a tool devoted to RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Mongo stores `databases` which stores `collections` which store documents. Documents inside a collection do not necessarily have same structures. As official docs [says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#list-all-indexes-for-a-database), you can use `mongo` shell to check all indexes inside collections of your db:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
   print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
   printjson(indexes);
});
```

if you want to create more indexes at once, you could try to loop over desired collections and then to use [`createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex)

AFAIK, there is not a tool which performs those kinds of operation just out of the box. You can try [robomongo](https://robomongo.org/), a kind of mysqlworkbench for Mongo. It could help you in your analyses.